# Locating a point in 2D using only differences between distances

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations

Let $R_1,R_2,R_3,R_4,T$ be points on a 2D plane, as in this figure.

[image]

$R_1,R_2,R_3,R_4$ are reference points with known positions. The goal is to find the position of $T$. $d$ is the Euclidean distance function, $p,q,r$ are known real numbers. We know the following distance **differences** only.
$$d(R_1,T)-d(R_2,T)=p$$
$$d(R_2,T)-d(R_3,T)=q$$
$$d(R_3,T)-d(R_4,T)=r$$

Can $R_1,R_2,R_3,R_4$ be chosen such that the location of T can be uniquely determined, regardless of T's location? If so, is there a formula that can be used to determine T's location?

For what it's worth, the same problem in terms of the Cartesian coordinate system gives the following equation system:
$$R_1=(a,b), R_2=(c,d), R_3=(e,f), R_4=(g,h), T=(x,y)$$
$$\sqrt{(a-x)^2+(b-y)^2}-\sqrt{(c-x)^2+(d-y)^2}=p$$
$$\sqrt{(c-x)^2+(d-y)^2}-\sqrt{(e-x)^2+(f-y)^2}=q$$
$$\sqrt{(e-x)^2+(f-y)^2}-\sqrt{(g-x)^2+(h-y)^2}=r$$